# CakePHP3 のテーマが機能しない

Tags: cakephp

## 環境

CakePHP 3.1.6

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/views/themes.html
に沿ってテンプレートを配置したが、テーマが機能せずに、デフォルトのLayoutとテンプレートファイルが使用されている。

## 実現したいこと

標準のテンプレートファイルは残したまま、サイト全体のテンプレート（見た目）を切り替えたい。CakePHPのテーマを使用すれば、容易にテンプレートを切り替えることができると、マニュアルから読み取ったのですが、意図したとおりに動作しない。
テーマは標準機能になっている。とマニュアルにありますが、未実装なのでしょうか。
どなたか教えていただければ、幸いです。

config/bootstrap.php

```
Plugin::load('Example');
```

src/Controller/AppController.php

```
$this->viewBuilder()->theme('Example');
```

plugins/Example/src/Template/Layout/example_nologin.ctp
plugins/Example/src/Template/Users/loginctp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

［自己解決］
AppController.php ではテーマが設定できないようです。（仕様？）
各コントローラで設定して動作しました。

src/Controller/UsersController.php

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->theme('Example');
}
```